# Adding a property to a function

Tags: javascript

You can assign a property to a function, but is that a good idea?
In this example, I'm showing that you can't create a property to a function *inside* the function, but you can *outside* it.

Q: Is a.questionable considered an ok JavaScript programming practice?

```js
function a() {
a.bad = 1
}
a.questionable = 2

function d() {
  console.log(a.bad)
  console.log(a.questionable)
}
d()
```

This question was inspired by [JavaScript: Understanding the Weird Parts](https://www.udemy.com/understand-javascript/learn/v4/t/lecture/2237524?start=0)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `this.bad = 1` instead? Since `a` is undefined in the function scope

Comment: ^ no, not unless `a` is a constructor

Comment: Creating the property inside the function works as well -- you just never called `a()` to run it.  Add `a();` to your code before you call `d()` and you'll get `1` output for `a.bad`.

Comment: @Damon Just tested it, and if I think about it, it actually makes sense, since it references the global scope. I just never would've expected that behavior. Thanks c:

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/8588847/7549867. yes you can add because function are also objects  but if you use a design pattern then it would always ask you to add property to the object and use function to modify it. Much like OOPS

Comment: You should probably never do the first one - I can't think of a situation where it would be beneficial. The second one, attaching a property to a function is an interesting side effect of functions also being objects in javascript - and should be perfectly fine to use if you like it. I've never found a use case for this behavior (read: never found a use case that can't be just as easily achieved with a more standard FP / OOP paradigm) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In this example, I'm showing that **you can't create a property to a function inside the function**, but you can outside it.

This is actually not the case. You can add properties to a function anywhere you have a reference to it. The problem is that you haven't called `a()` and so the line `a.bad = 1` has never had a chance to run.

```js
function a() {
a.bad = 1
}
a.questionable = 2

function d() {
  console.log(a.bad)
  console.log(a.questionable)
}
a()
d()
```

> Q: Is `a.questionable` considered an ok JavaScript programming practice?

jQuery uses it quite extensively (think `jQuery.fn`, `jQuery.extend`, etc.) — so no, I don't think it is considered a "bad" programming practice per se. In fact, adding properties to a constructor function was the only way to mimic static fields and methods before ES6 introduced them as a part of [`class` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

```js
function Constructor() {

}
Constructor.staticMethod = function () {
  return "I'm a static method!"
}

Constructor.staticProperty = "I'm a static property!"

console.log(
  Constructor.staticMethod(),
  Constructor.staticProperty
)
```

Comment: Oops. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

It’s fine to put properties on functions. In fact, that’s exactly what static methods are on ES6 classes, which is the only use of `static`; consider it explicit language support.

```
class Foo {
    static bar() {}
}

'bar' in Foo  // true
typeof Foo    // 'function'
```

> In this example, I'm showing that you can't create a property to a function inside the function, but you can outside it.

You can create a property on a function inside that function, but it’s unreasonable to expect the body of a function to run without calling it.

Comment: Oops. Sorry about that.