# How can I set a JS object's property to both call a function and also be a nested hash?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Bit of a weird one. I'm fascinated with the `context` object in Azure, although I have not been able to find the full source code for it.

When using it within Azure function apps, you can do both `context.log` and `context.log.error`. I'm trying to replicate this in a local mock like so:

```
let context = {
  log(message){
    console.log(message)
  },

  log: {
    info: console.log,
    error: console.error
  }
}
```

But clearly the second `log` property overrides the function so I can't do both context.log and context.log.error.

I also tried

```
let context = {
  'log': console.log,
  'log.error': console.error
}
```

But here, `context.log.error` is undefined, however `context['log.error']` works.

Eventually, I found one that does work:

```
let context = {
  'log': console.log,
}
context.log['error'] = console.error
context.log['info'] = console.log
```

Which does do what i want:

```
context.log('message') // prints 'message'
context.log.error('message') // prints error 'message'
```

But I would like to understand why that last bit worked, and additionally, how I can declare all of it in one go instead of relying on `context.log[error] = value`

Comment: In js, functions are objects. In other words, `function f() {}; f.myProperty = 0;` is valid.

Comment: Just as an additional mention to avoid pitfalls: an answer below already wrapped things in a new function. That's because in your last version, after your assignments, e.g. `console.log.error === console.error`, so you are bleeding into native APIs, which is often undesirable. That's to be expected, given that you assign on the function itself, but i better mention it anyways.

Comment: Oh that's a great catch, yeah. Just to make sure I'm getting this right: I assigned a native function (console.log) to context.log, then I added a property to it via ````context.log['error'] =```` . Which is why the answer below is instead creating a new function to which these properties are being passed, right? Nice! Thank you!

Comment: I guess you are using Azure functions with Javascript and ran into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create a function object, and then assign properties to that. You can do that in the object literal with `Object.assign`:

```
 {
    log: Object.assign(function log() { /*...*/ }, {
       error() { /*...*/ },
    }),
 }
```

Comment: Fascinating! I see, so since functions are objects in JS, you can actually assign properties to them, and a way to do this would be to use Object.assign?

Comment: Exactly. That's also why your third version works.

Comment: This comment + @asdfgerte's explanation above answered the question nicely. I also found this stackoverflow question which expands on it further:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588563/adding-custom-properties-to-a-function/20734003