# Why Object.assign is not present in Object Prototype (properties & methods)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Object sits at the very base of the JS Data-Structures. Whatever other data-types we say (Arrays, Promises, Date, Strings, Numbers, Functions, Boolean, Maps, Sets, etc.) --- have Object as their upstream in the `prototype chain` so they may access all its properties and methods.

Now, even Object has got a set of its own properties & methods, which it might access when it needs.

`Object.prototype` gives set of its properties and methods.

`Object.assign` Now returns some function.

The strange thing is I expected `assign() function` to be a method up in the Object-prototype chain. Why is it not present? Shouldn't ideally be it should be there ?? If NOT, how object is able to use it?

Also, Object.prototype.prototype will give you `null` as there is nothing above it.

**consider:**

[image]

Comment: How to the above 2 links explain my question? It is so bad, that nowadays people just come and mark duplicate, when my question is not explained in those 2 links given.

Comment: "*I expected assign() function to be a method up in the Object-prototype chain. Why is it not present? Shouldn't ideally be it should be there?*" is exactly the question that those two canonicals answer (sure, they were asked about ES5, but the same design methodology applies to ES6 `Object.assign`). Were you asking something else?

Comment: Yes, but we may only use items which are in `prototype`. So, since when this new way started? Was is started in ES6, ES7, ES8, or from before. If so, why the rest of properties and methods are present in `Object.prototype`? They should also not be present. Why is the separate behavior with `Object.assign()`? How will the end user then find, what exactly is list of methods that can be used with `Object, array, string` or whatever then. It becomes so obscure and unlisted then.

Comment: "*but we may only use items which are in `prototype`*" - no. Since ES1, all you need to define a method is an object (including [function objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8588563), see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/705173)) with a function property. "*Why is the separate behavior with Object.assign()?*" - `Object.assign` is by far not the only static native method. `Array.isArray`, `Object.create`, `Map.from`…. "*How will the end user then find, what exactly is list of methods*" - by reading [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects).