# Confusion over references to functions with properties in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reference

In the following javascript code:

```
function foo() {
  foo.val =  foo.val || 'no val';
  return 'foo has ' + foo.val;
};
function bar() {
  bar.val =  bar.val || 'no val';
  return 'bar has ' + bar.val;
};
var a = foo;
foo.val = '1';
bar.val = '2';
a.val = '3';
foo = bar;
'foo says "' + foo() + '", bar says "' + bar() + '", a says "' + a() +'"';
```

what I would expect would be:

> foo says "bar has 2", bar says "bar has 2", a says "foo has 3"

However, when run from the Firebug console in Firefox 10.0.2 I get:

> foo says "bar has 2", bar says "bar has 2", a says "foo has 2"

Can anyone explain to me the sequence of events that goes on behind the scenes to make this so? Why does `a` stay bound to the original `foo` function (as I would expect) but hold `bar`'s value for `val`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After this line of code:

```
var a = foo;
```

`a` points to the same function that `foo` points to. In

```
foo = bar;
```

you reassign `foo` to point to whatever `bar` refers to. This doesn't update `a`'s reference — it still points to the function that `foo` also originally pointed to.

Now, when you run `a()`, the original function is executed. It grabs `foo` (which now points to `bar`'s reference) and gets its `val` property. The `val` of `bar`'s object is 2, so this is what is returned.

It's a bit difficult to explain in words.. would a diagram be easier to understand, perhaps?

Comment: +1. It is confusing to explain, but I think you did a better job than I did.

Comment: No need for a diagram, it's a good explanation. I was looking for a way to reference the function without `arguments.callee`, since it raises a TypeError in ES5 strict mode. I'll just have to be careful not to reassign my function, I guess.

Answer (score 4):

When the `foo()` function executes via the `a()` call, its code says to get the value of `foo.val`, that is, the `val` property of whatever `foo` refers to at that moment. So your `a()` function effectively looks like this:

```
function a() {
  foo.val =  foo.val || 'no val';
  return 'foo has ' + foo.val;
};
```

But `foo` at that point is just a reference to `bar`.

Comment: Ahhh. I had thought (hoped) that the call to `foo.val` in the foo function definition would be bound to the original. Thanks for clearing that one up.